# Altbeacon BackgroundPowerSaver property

Tags: android, altbeacon

According to the documentation found [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html), the BackgroundPowerSaver should be an instance member in your Application class.

```
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    }
}
```

This of course generates a `Field can be local` warning.

---

My question is, why should it be an instance member?

Since it [registers on the Application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/powersave/BackgroundPowerSaver.java), the Application adds the BackgroundPowerSaver to its `mActivityLifecycleCallbacks` ArrayList. (See Application source code for this)

If I'm not mistaken, this should mean that the Application keeps a reference to the BackgroundPowerSaver and it should not be GC'ed.

So, Shouldn't it work if you do this?

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Something needs to hold a reference to the `BackgroundPowerSaver` instance to keep it from being garbage collected by the virtual machine.</strike>  If you want to remove the warning, you can simply add a @SuppressWarnings annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
// Need to hold a reference to prevent garbage collection
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver
```

**EDIT:** The Background power saver used to have different configurable internal implementations, only one of which used Android ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.  For this reason it was once necessary to hold a reference.  The latest version always uses this technique, so there is no longer any reason to hold a reference.

**Bottom line, the code shown in the question will work just fine.**

Comment: But doesn't the Application keep a reference to it in the `mActivityLifecycleCallbacks` ArrayList?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!